# Random tips. Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want my bot to send random tips out of a list of tips whenever a command is run.

Also, I want it to show the tips only sometimes.

What I mean to say is, for example, a user types the command `hi` then it should say ofcourse `hi`. But the tips should be shown only when the command is run a certain amount of times.

So if the command is run 5 times, then what I would like is that every 5 times my command is executed, one tip should be shown.

**It is not like I have a command that sends random tips.**

For example, if I have an unban command, it could send a tip every 5 times a command is run like, "You can also use kick and ban commands. Use `-help` for more info."

I hope you get what I am trying to say and this is all the information you need.

This is inspired by Dank Memer

Answer (score 0):

Just store a counter somehow and use the `random` module to select a random tip

If using functions for commands:

```py
import random
hi_counter = 0
hi_tips = [
  "You can also use kick and ban commands. Use `-help` for more info.",
  "a tip",
  "another tip",
  "yet another tip",
]

@bot.command('hi')
async def hi(ctx):
  global hi_counter, hi_tips
  await ctx.send('hi')
  hi_counter += 1
  if hi_counter % 5 == 0:
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(random.choice(hi_tips))
```

If you're using a Cog for commands:

```py
import random

class hi(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
    self.counter = 0
    self.tips = [
      "You can also use kick and ban commands. Use `-help` for more info.",
      "a tip",
      "another tip",
      "yet another tip",
    ]

  @commands.command('hi')
  async def hi(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send('hi')
    self.counter += 1
    if self.counter % 5 == 0:
      await asyncio.sleep(1)
      await ctx.send(random.choice(self.tips))

def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(hi(bot))
```

If you want to make a decorator for this, you can do that too:

```py
import random

def tips(times: int, tips: List[str]):
  counter = 0

  def decorator(func):
    nonlocal counter, tips
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      nonlocal counter, tips
      ctx = func(*args, **kwargs)
      counter += 1
      if counter % times == 0:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await ctx.send(random.choice(tips))
    return wrapper
  return decorator

# Use it like:
@bot.command('hi')
@tips(5, [
  "You can also use kick and ban commands. Use `-help` for more info.",
  "a tip",
  "another tip",
  "yet another tip",
])
async def hi(ctx):
  global hi_counter, hi_tips
  await ctx.send('hi')
  return ctx # MAKE SURE TO RETURN `ctx` OR THE DECORATOR WON'T WORK
```

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, however, could you just explain your answer a bit. Since I am kinda new to discord.py. Your explaination would be really appreciated.